# Probability of hitting the target in up to 5 shots

Tags: probability

What is the probability of one shooter to hit the target in up to $5$ shots (max $5$ shots)?

Probability of shooter to hit the target is $0.8$.

Can this problem be solved with binomial?

Suppose $N = 5$ and $K = 1$ (the hit) :

$$\binom{5}{1} \cdot 0.8^1 \cdot (1 - 0.8)^4$$

Comment: You're correct. Now go for $k=2, 3,4,5$ and add them.

Comment: Alternatively, why don't you find the probability of not shooting the target in $5$ turns, which is straightforward, and then subtract from $1$?

Comment: @MathLover The question confuses me, because it says UP TO 5 shots, that means target can be hit by the shooter in 1st, 2nd,...5th try. I don't know if that makes sense for the solution of the problem.

Comment: It is same thing. Please see the explanation below.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Probability of not shooting the target in five turns $ = 0.2^5 = 0.00032$.

So, probability of shooting the target in up to five turns $ = 1 - 0.00032 = 0.99968$.

It is same as below -

The probability of shooting the target in exactly one turn  $= 0.8$
The probability of shooting in exactly two turns $= 0.2 \times 0.8$
The probability of shooting in exactly three turns $= 0.2^2 \times 0.8$
The probability of shooting in exactly four turns $= 0.2^3 \times 0.8$
The probability of shooting in exactly five turns $= 0.2^4 \times 0.8$

So to find the probability of shooting the target in up to five turns, add all of the above and it comes to $0.99968$.